# CompletableFuture cannot be cast to CustomCompletableFuture

Tags: java, spring, subclass, completable-future

So I'm trying to create a CustomCompletableFuture and override the get, I don't have to handle all the exceptions every time I use it, my code looks like this:

The custom completable is like this:

```
public class CustomCompletableFuture<T> extends CompletableFuture<T> {

    @Override
    public T get(long timeOut, TimeUnit unit) {
        try {
            return super.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            if (e instanceof InterruptedException) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            if (e.getCause() instanceof ServiceSystemException) {
                throw (ServiceSystemException) e.getCause();
            } else if (e.getCause() instanceof ServiceBusinessException) {
                throw (ServiceBusinessException) e.getCause();
            }
            throw ExceptionBuilder.buildServiceSystemException(EXTERNAL_SERVICE_EXCEPTION,
                    ServiceExceptionCodeMap.getErrorDescription(EXTERNAL_SERVICE_EXCEPTION),
                    ServiceExceptionCodeMap.getErrorMessageFormat(EXTERNAL_SERVICE_EXCEPTION));
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the usage:

```
CustomCompletableFuture<List<Student>> future1Student = getStudentsByProperty(propertyId, propertyCode);
List<Student> students = future1Student.get(futuresExecutorConfigurationProperties.getRatePlanSeasonTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

private CustomCompletableFuture<List<Student>> getStudentsByProperty(String propertyId, String propertyCode) {
        Map<String, String> parentMDCContext = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
            return (CustomCompletableFuture<List<Student>>) CustomCompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                try {
                    MDC.setContextMap(parentMDCContext);
                    return internalService.internalCall();
                } finally {
                    MDC.clear();
                }
            }, getSeasonExecutor);
        }
```

Comment: So, does `supplyAsync()` return a `CustomCompletableFuture` or a `CompletableFuture`? Do you understand how casting actually works?

Comment: Couple things: (1) You're breaking the contract of `get()` by unwrapping the cause of the `ExecutionException`. (2) The `supplyAsync` method is a static method defined by `CompletableFuture`. Just because you did `CustomCompletableFuture.supplyAsync(...)` does not change that. In other words, `supplyAsync` returns a "pure" `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: Ok I get it, so can I make something to return a "pure" CompletableFuture but still use the get I just override? Since we want to use a couple of them wrapping every CompletableFuture in a try catch block can be a little bit clunky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`CompletableFuture#supplyAsync(Supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync(java.util.function.Supplier)) is a static method. When you do:

> ```java
> CustomCompletableFuture.supplyAsync(...);
> ```

You're still calling the method declared in `CompletableFuture`, meaning the method is not returning a `CustomCompletableFuture`. Note static methods cannot be overridden. Though if you were to define a static method with the same signature in the subclass, then it would "hide" the static method in the superclass. That is not likely something you want to do.

That said, I recommend you *do not* subclass `CompletableFuture` this way. By unwrapping the cause of the `ExecutionException` and throwing it directly, you are breaking the contract of [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). If you need this exception  handling in multiple places, I suggest creating a utility method.

```java
public static <T> T getServiceResult(Future<T> future, Duration timeout) throws TimeoutException {
    TimeUnit unit = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS;
    try {
        return future.get(unit.convert(timeout), unit);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
        if (ex instanceof InterruptedException) {        
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        // "JEP 394: Pattern Matching for instanceof" added in Java 16
        if (ex.getCause() instanceof ServiceSystemException sse) {
            throw sse;
        } else if (ex.getCause() instanceof ServiceBusinessException sbe) {
            throw sbe;
        }

        throw ExceptionBuilder.buildServiceSystemException(
                EXTERNAL_SERVICE_EXCEPTION,
                ServiceExceptionCodeMap.getErrorDescription(EXTERNAL_SERVICE_EXCEPTION),
                ServiceExceptionCodeMap.getErrorMessageFormat(EXTERNAL_SERVICE_EXCEPTION));
    }
}
```

Then you can call this like so:

```java
CompletableFuture<List<Student>> future = getStudentsByProperty(propertyId, propertyCode);

long timeoutMillis = futuresExecutorConfigurationProperties.getRatePlanSeasonTimeout();
List<Student> students = getServiceResult(future, Duration.ofMillis(timeoutMillis));
```

Where `getStudentsByProperty` returns a standard `CompletableFuture`.